# Best use adding user generated JS/CSS to a theme with a plugin

Tags: plugins, css, javascript, footer, wp-head

I want to know the best use of adding custom `JS/CSS` to a theme.

I have built a small plugin which has a section to allow users to add `CSS/JS` to their theme. Now I am trying to figure out is which is the best way to do this:

> 1. Save all of the code inside an custom DB and load this as plain code inside the header/footer.
> 2. Save all of the code inside an custom js/css file(no DB)  and add the file inside the /header/footer

Notice: these custom JS/CSS files are custom build by the users so the user can add the own rules inside the plugin.

Which is the better, most secure solution?

Answer (score 1):

I actually ran into a similar issue yesterday. A theme I was working with was adding 500+ lines of internal styles to the header which absolutely drives me nuts! I ended up finding a clever solution online to work around this which you could use for CSS. The JavaScript side I'll explain toward the bottom.

**--- :: CSS :: ---**

There's a few key points in how this code works. Since you need to handle variables in your CSS files we *need* to make sure the file given supports PHP **and** has access to WordPress functions so to get any presets. We cannot do this using a `.css` file alone so we need to fool the server into presenting our PHP file as CSS.

This is purely for testing purposes: Create a file called `customcss.php` with the following code, note the PHP [`header()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) function needed to tell the server we're going to show `text/css`:

```
<?php
    header( "Content-type: text/css; charset: UTF-8" );
    $test = 'blue';
?>

body    {color: <?php echo $test; ?>;}
```

Next, we need to load this file in the context of WordPress so that we still have access to functions such as `get_post_meta()` or any `global` variables. Let's include this "css" file using [WP AJAX](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_ajax_(action)). Note, when including or requiring we need to use absolute paths. This will look for your plugin folder and into the `/css/` directory for your "css" php file.

```
function plugin_dynamicss() {
    include_once( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . '/css/customcss.php' );
    exit;
}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_plugin_dynamicss', 'plugin_dynamicss' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_plugin_dynamicss', 'plugin_dynamicss' );
```

Finally, we need to actually enqueue our CSS via [`wp_enqueue_scripts`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_enqueue_scripts) hook:

```
function plugin_enqueue_css() {
    wp_enqueue_style(
        'dynamicss', admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) . '?action=plugin_dynamicss',
        array(),
        '',
        'screen'
    );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'plugin_enqueue_css' );
```

---

**--- :: JavaScript :: ---**

Enqueueing JS with variables is much easier with [`wp_localize_script()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script). All you need to do is [register the script](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_register_script), [localize the script](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script) with data, and finally [enqueue the script](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script).

```
function plugin_enqueue_js() {
    wp_register_script( 'plugin_js', plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . '/js/customjs.js' );

    $data = array(                      // Define Our Data
        'robert'    => 'bobbert',
        'nine'      => 'nein'
    );

    wp_localize_script( 'plugin_js', 'plugin_data', $data );    // Localize Our Data

    wp_enqueue_script( 'plugin_js' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'plugin_enqueue_js' );
```

The 2nd parameter of `wp_localize_script()` actually defines our JS Object name. In our object if we want to get and use one of the values we can say: `alert( plugin_data.robert );` which will alert to the screen "bobbert".

Answer (score -1):

You've probably came across several different methods for including JavaScript and CSS.

There is one primary method recommended in the [WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org).

The safe and recommended method of adding JavaScript to a WordPress generated page, and WordPress Theme or Plugin, is by using [wp_enqueue_script()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script). This function includes the script if it hasn't already been included, and safely handles dependencies.

A safe way to add/enqueue a stylesheet file to the WordPress generated page. Use  `wp_enqueue_style( $handle, $src, $deps, $ver, $media );` This function [wp_enqueue_style()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_style) does not return a value.

Comment: How does OP handle the user variables in JS / CSS with wp_enqueue_style / script? `...which allows users to add some CSS/JS to their theme...`

Comment: I know these function which I alrady use for the core files, but users can generate there own code and this I have to add to the theme